# python seaborn: alpha by hue

Tags: python, seaborn

In seaborn, hue sets different colors for the groups. Can I set `alpha` depending on the group in `JointGrid`? Or even on individual datapoints?

```
sns.set_theme()
jg = sns.JointGrid(data=df_sns, x='x', y='y', hue='hue')
jg.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
jg.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, kde=False)

jg.set_axis_labels(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
jg.fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: I am voting for @JohanC. The answer is more versatile and convenient in plotting marginal distribution.

Comment: Surely. I have just done so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Update: using `to_rgba()` as suggested in the comments.)

You could create a `palette` which contains colors with alpha. A simple way to create such colors is with the hexadecimal format: `'#RRGGBBAA'`. Or you can convert any matplotlib color to rgb and add an alpha, as in the example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.JointGrid(data=iris, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species')
color_dict = {'setosa': to_rgba('cornflowerblue', 1),
              'versicolor': to_rgba('crimson', 0.7),
              'virginica': to_rgba('turquoise', 0.4)}
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, palette=color_dict)
g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, kde=False, palette=color_dict, multiple='stack')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: joint plot with alpha]

Comment: If you can do this, you don't need to bother with the looping process. Is there any information about this in the official reference? It was a good experience.

Comment: Nice! BTW: `matplotlib.colors.to_rgba` provides the same interface as your custom function here.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty JoinGrid and set up a scatter plot and histogram for each. In the scatter plot, I set the transparency and color for the data extracted in the categories that I want to separate the transparency. Please refer to the [official reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid).

```
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.JointGrid()
x, y = penguins["bill_length_mm"], penguins["bill_depth_mm"]
color_dict = dict({'Male': 'C0', 'Female': 'C1'})

for _,gr in penguins.groupby('sex'):
    if _ == 'Male':
        alpha = 1.0
    else:
        alpha = 0.5
    sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, hue='sex', data=gr, ax=g.ax_joint, s=100, alpha=alpha, palette=color_dict)
        
sns.histplot(x=x, kde=False, ax=g.ax_marg_x)
sns.histplot(y=y, kde=False, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
```

[image]