# Specify Matplotlib's kwargs to Seaborn's displot when hue is used

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose we have this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

samples = 2**13

data = pd.DataFrame({'Values': list(np.random.normal(size=samples)) + list(np.random.uniform(size=samples)), 
                     'Kind': ['Normal'] * samples + ['Uniform'] * samples})

sns.displot(data, hue='Kind', x='Values', fill=True)
```

[image]

I want my Normal's histogram (or KDE) emphasized. I'd like it in red and non transparent in the background. Uniform should have `alpha = .5`.

How do I specify these style parameters in a "per hue" manner?

Comment: I dont know if that is possible as displot is a figure level plot (could be wrong). Might be possible with histplot if that works... You can plot each (Normal, Uniform) Kind separately with different alphas and plot them together

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with two separate histplots on the same Axes, as @Redox suggested. We can basically recreate the same plot, but with fine-grade control over colours and alpha. However I had to explicitly pass the number of bins in to get the same plot as yours. I also needed to define the colour for `Uniform` otherwise a ghost element would be added to the legend! I used `C1`, meaning the first default colour.

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data=data[data.Kind=='Normal'], x="Values", ax=ax, label='Normal', color='tab:red',bins=130,alpha=1)
sns.histplot(data=data[data.Kind=='Uniform'], x="Values", ax=ax, label='Uniform', color='C1',bins=17, alpha=.5)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Note that if you just want to set the colour without alpha you can already do this on a displot via the `palette` argument - pass in a dictionary of your unique `hue` values to colour names. However, the `alpha` that you pass in must be a scalar. I tried to use [this clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66671457/6220759) to set colours as RGBA colours which include alpha, which seems to work with other figure level plots in Seaborn. However, `displot` overrides this and sets the alpha separately!